# How can I check if list exist in list of lists?

Tags: python

Python newbie here.

If I'm trying to check if single element exists in list,I can use 'in' operation like

```
a in b
```

But now I'm trying to find the way to check if list exist in list of lists.
For example,

```
a = [[1,3],[1,4],[2,5],[3,1]]
b = [1,3]
```

How can I check there is 'b' in list 'a'?

Comment: You can just do `b in a`. It works for a list in a list of lists as well.

Comment: The `in` operator internally uses the `==` operator to determine whether a value is inside a collection.  This `==` operator works for lists as well and compares them element-wise.  So even if your `b` is a different entity of the list `[1, 3]`, it will be _equal_ to the `[1, 3]` in your list `a`, and the `in` operator will find that and return `True`.

Answer (score 0):

You can check that using 'in' operator as:

```
a = [[1,3],[1,4],[2,5],[3,1]]
b = [1,3]

if b in a:
    print(f"{b} exists in {a}")
```